# htaccess: Can't check dynamic file existence!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements, filepath

I have written a on-the-fly thumbnail creator by an htaccess file looking to see if the requested file exists and if not sending the user to a php page to create it. My htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Check the formatting (this works)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}%{QUERY_STRING} /([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).(jpg|gif|png)w=([0-9]+)&h=([0-9]+)(&c=(true|false))

# Only forward to thumbnail.php if file doesn't exist
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   #this works but not for the correct filename!
RewriteCond %1-%2-%3-%4-%6.jpg !-f     # Doesn't work!!!

# If file doesn't exist, send here: (this works)
RewriteRule ^.*$ thumbnail.php?file_name=%1&type=%2&w=%3&h=%4&c=%6
```

My check of the file's existence does not seem to work however... the old version that uses `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` works, but that is not the correct filename I need to check. I have verified that the new file `%1-%2-%3-%4-%6.jpg` has the correct output, but does not trigger the condition!

Based on this URL:

```
this-is-the-image-name.gif?w=200&h=100&c=true
```

The htaccess file should check if this file exists:

```
this-is-the-image-name-gif-200-100-true.jpg
```

The thumbnails and htaccess file are both in the same folder, but this folder is unknown and can't be hardcoded. Does it need the full path to check? If so, how can I get the full path but with my custom filename?

Pulling my hair out with this one... **PLEASE** help! Thank you.

Comment: That's a good mod-rewrite question, I'm adding the mod-rewrite tag, but you should try to ask it on ServFault, you'll find some mod-rewrite genius on this place.

Comment: Where is the **thumbnail.php** file located?

Comment: @Creadiff The thumbnail.php file is located in the same directory (media/thumbnails/) as the thumbnail files to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your PHP script to replace the traditional "404 Error" page :

```
ErrorDocument 404 thumbnail.php
```

Then, you can retrieve the requested URL using PHP :

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Parameters can be retrieved using the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) function.

Comment: Well it would always give a 404 since no file name I am requesting would exist since I am using query strings to set the size. I'm not sure how much of a speed difference there would be, but I am trying to avoid images that exist having to be routed by a php file... which is what it currently does (file_exist in the PHP file).

Comment: Why don't you name your pictures directly like this: **this-is-the-image-name-gif-200-100-true.jpg**? You wouldn't need any rewriting. As such, existing images would directly be sent by Apache, and only PHP-generated images would be routed by PHP scripts (which would happen much less often I guess).

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was initially doing, but the client prefers this syntax. I have a [sister-question going on here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348045/fastest-way-to-redirect-missing-image-files/) where I try and resolve this side of the problem.