# php load image for non-existing wildcard image link (broken image with folder(s))

Tags: php

Case: User navigates to an image location on a site in their browser, for example: `http://www.example.com/u1n1uxun8uxd0n1uxdu4n2uxd0n1uxd4un2uxd0nu1xd4u4xd0n1uxdu1d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxdunod0uiui0uxd0n1uxduo0d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4uiui0uxd0n1uxd4/ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4uiui0uxd0n1uxdu1d0ucuc0uxd0nu1xdunod0uiui0uxd0n1uxduo0d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4u4xd0n1ux5un2ux1n2u6n3u1n;n(.png`

Notice there is a forward slash in that URL.

I want any broken image to use mod_rewrite that takes the non-existing image directory and filename, without the domain, and send it to a php script and make an image out of that. It does not matter what the image is, it just also needs to know what the directory filename is.

How do you make any broken image link that the user navigates to or is on a website run the script to create that image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to redirect missing image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348045/fastest-way-to-redirect-missing-image-files), Just add a default redirect to a script which loads your default

Comment: It's interesting but it doesn't answer exactly what I want to do. I want to send the entire current URL to a php script. mod_rewrite and php is all I need I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can to do that with nginx, try something like

```
server {
    // server configs

    location ~ \.png {
        try_files $uri /pngimages.php;
    }

    // server configs
}
```